# How to place main in the first image with linker

Tags: c++, class, linker, program-entry-point

Now, I make a new OS which is written in C++.

I want to place the main function at the first location in the image, but I could not.

If I do not use class, the main is first .

If I use class, the class is located at the first location of the image.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00010200 <_ZN4test4initEv>:
_ZN4test4initEv():
/home/xaliver/WorkSpace/kOdin/kernel32/./test.hpp:11
public:
    void init(void);
};

void test::init(void)
{
   10200:   55                      push   %ebp 
   10201:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
/home/xaliver/WorkSpace/kOdin/kernel32/./test.hpp:12
    m = 10;
   10203:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   10206:   c7 00 0a 00 00 00       movl   $0xa,(%eax)
/home/xaliver/WorkSpace/kOdin/kernel32/./test.hpp:14

    return;
   1020c:   90                      nop
/home/xaliver/WorkSpace/kOdin/kernel32/./test.hpp:15
}
   1020d:   5d                      pop    %ebp 
   1020e:   c3                      ret    

0001020f <main>:
main():
/home/xaliver/WorkSpace/kOdin/kernel32/./main.cpp:10
bool kPrintString(int iX, int iY, const char* pcString);
bool kInitializeKernel64Area(void);
bool kIsMemoryEnough(void);

void main(void)
{
   1020f:   55                      push   %ebp 
   10210:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   10212:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
```

I use this linker script. 0x10200 is the first location

```
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386", "elf32-i386",
          "elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/x86_64-pc-linux/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x08048000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x08048000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;

  /* DS Start */
  /* Part moved to the front by section relocation */
  .text 0x10200   :
  {
    main.o(.text)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  } =0x90909090

  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }

  /* Align start of data at the sector size */
  . = ALIGN (512);  /* Next .data will be located at aligned address by 512 byte */

  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
    *(.dynbss)
    *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
    *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 32 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(32 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  . = ALIGN(32 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  /* DS End */

  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rel.init       : { *(.rel.init) }
  .rel.text       : { *(.rel.text .rel.text.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.t.*) }
  .rel.fini       : { *(.rel.fini) }
  .rel.rodata     : { *(.rel.rodata .rel.rodata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rel.data.rel.ro   : { *(.rel.data.rel.ro .rel.data.rel.ro.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .rel.data       : { *(.rel.data .rel.data.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.*) }
  .rel.tdata      : { *(.rel.tdata .rel.tdata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .rel.tbss   : { *(.rel.tbss .rel.tbss.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.tb.*) }
  .rel.ctors      : { *(.rel.ctors) }
  .rel.dtors      : { *(.rel.dtors) }
  .rel.got        : { *(.rel.got) }
  .rel.bss        : { *(.rel.bss .rel.bss.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.b.*) }
  .rel.ifunc      : { *(.rel.ifunc) }
  .rel.plt        :
    {
      *(.rel.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rel_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rel.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rel_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array ))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array ))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }

  //_edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);

  /* Thread Local Storage sections */
  .tdata      : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  //. = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 12 ? 12 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)); . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}
```

How can I set the main at the first location?